# Web site stops responding until cookie is deleted

Tags: php, apache, cookies

I have a Web site running on Apache/PHP.

The Web site only uses cookies for storing PHPSESSID.

Some users that uses the Web Side 24/7 sometimes experience that the site does not respond at all. And the only solution is to delete the cookie in the browser.

Any suggestions on what can cause this problem?

Maybe the session is corrupt?

Comment: Need more info. Custom app or not ?

Comment: Custom app. Uses sessions to store all kinds of data about the user and temporary searches/filters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it could happen because of session.

If some long running code locks the session file (maybe just call session_start), then other pages that use session also will be blocked.